# What is the problem installing pip in python?

Tags: python, pip

I just want to install pip in my system. Why is it showing this message?

[image]

What to do? How to install it?

For assure I have installed python 3.9 which includes pip but didn't recognize it.

[image]

By command `python -m pip --version` , shows me:

[image]

My installation path => C:\Python39

[image]

Comment: If you have installed Python you probably have the pip installed as well already out of the box. Try `pip --version`.

Comment: yes but it said that it didn't recognized.

Comment: @asifsadek, what about `python -m pip --version` ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer shows me no module name pip.

Comment: did you make sure your environment variable PATH is configured correctly, i.e. contains paths to the python directory and the scripts folder?

Comment: you might want to try reinstalling python and make sure you choose to install pip. How did you install python in the first place though?

Comment: are you sur you are using the right python ? `python --version`

Comment: yes ,please see it the description again .

Comment: Try this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#command-line-interface

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in the same path where you have put your `get-pip.py` file.

Please try the command below

```
python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=/local/copies
```

You can try doing it through conda as well.
You can install anaconda and then using conda you can install pip

That way you'll be able to make use of the virtual environments as well!

Once you install anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual
you can use the command below to install pip!

```
conda install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

1. Download `get-pip.py` file. You can download it from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. Open command prompt and navigate to the folder in which you have downloaded `get-pip.py` file.
3. Run `python get-pip.py` or `py get-pip.py`